Analytical solution to a set of coupled pdes
I have simplified a set of partial differential equations ane arrived at the following equations
$\partial_t a(y,t) + \partial_y[ a(y,t) u(y,t)]=0,$
$\partial_y[ a(y,t) \: (m+ 3 \frac{\partial_y u(y,t)}{L(t)}+\frac{3 }{2}\frac{\partial_y \partial_t u(y,t)}{L(t)})]=0,$
$\partial_t L(t)= u(1,t),$
where $m$ and $b$ are arbitrary constants. I wonder if these could be solved analytically for a set of boundary and initial conditions.
Here is an example of boundary conditions
$m+ 3  \frac{\partial_y u(1,t)}{L(t)}+\frac{3 }{2}\frac{\partial_y \partial_t u(1,t)}{L(t)}=0,$
$u(0,t)=1,$
$L(t=0)=5,$
$a(0,t)=5^b$
$a(y,t)=(5-y)^b$
$u(y,0)=1+ \alpha y$
Could anyone please help me with this?
